# Load a JLD file in Python

Tags: python, julia

I have a database created in Julia with the [JLD Package](https://github.com/JuliaIO/JLD.jl)

This database contains 2 elements: input and output

In julia, I can load it with the following code:

```
using JLD

data_in = load("file_path")["input"]
1×5 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2  3  4  5

data_out = load("file_path")["output"]
1×5 Array{Int64,2}:
 3  6  9  12  15
```

I would like to load these arrays in Python. I tried the following (in Python):

```
filename = "file_path"

data = open(filename, r)
```

data returns the following:

```
data
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='file_path' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

After that, I read a document that explained how to [read a file](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python). Nevertheless, if I run the following:

```
print(data.readlines())
```

I have only this output:

```
[]
```

Is it possible to load these arrays in Python ?

**EDIT**

I tried to do an equivalent of Julia:

```
data = open("file_path")["input"]
```

But there is this error:

```
TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable
```

Maybe there is an other function to read a file ?

Comment: Have you read the documentation for [**`open`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)? It returns a [fileobject](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object)

Comment: The part to [read a file](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python), yes. But if I do  `data.readlines()` I have only `[]`

Comment: regardless of whether you get an exact answer to your question, opening a JLD file in python is probably not the way to go. if you're generating the jld files yourself, consider saving to a different format which you know for sure is handled the same way by python. (and if you don't have access to the generating code but you have access to a julia interpreter, write a small script to perform such conversion yourself)

Comment: Fully agreed with Tasos.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Julia JLD files have HDF5 format so you can read them using e.g. `h5py` like this:

```
import h5py
f = h5py.File("filename", "r")
f["input"].value, f["output"].value
```

The file will also contain an entry `_creator` with metadata saved by Julia.

Note that Julia stores data in column major order, as opposed to row major used by `numpy`, so if you would read matrices this way they would be transposed.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue to solve and I did the following:

1. I read the JLD file in julia:

   `data = load("filename_julia.jld")["data"]`
2. Converted into an array by numpy.asarray using PyCall to invoke numpy,

   using PyCall:

   `np = pyimport("numpy")`

   `data = np.asarray(data)`
3. I then saved the array as .npy file using numpy.save:

   `np.save("filename_python.npy",data)`

You can then open this file in python as a regular .npy file